# ArcPy error handling within a C# wrapper

Tags: arcpy, c#, error, .net, debugging

I'm running arcPy commands from a C# script i.e.

```
RunPythonScript("arcpy.Delete_management(\"C:\\\\Temp\\\\NW\\\\land.gdb\", \"Table\")");

private static void RunPythonScript(string script)
        {
            try
            {
                Stopwatch stpw = new Stopwatch();
                stpw.Start();

                string pyfile = "C:\\Temp\\cmd.py";

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pyfile);
                sw.WriteLine("import arcpy");
                sw.WriteLine("from arcpy import env");
                sw.Write(script);
...
```

The problem is this makes debugging very difficult without viewing error messages produced in Python. How can I write errors to a log file or otherwise view the errors being produced by my ArcPy commands?

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/C-and-Python-interprocess-171378ee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear how you are running your Python script from .NET, so I will assume that you are using System.Diagnostics.Process

```
Process proc = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\python.exe";
        Arguments = "<your python file>"
        RedirectStandardError = true; //error output
        RedirectStandardOutput = true; //other output
    }
}

proc.Start();
string all_error_output = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();  //read any errors
string all_normal_output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();  //read any output
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution was to access my cmd.py which passes the python command being processed and copying that command and running it in the python command window in ArcMap.